# Or grammar in python

Tags: python-2.7

I'm trying to understand the difference in results of these two options and possibly get a better option. I'm a newbie but my instruction isn't very detailed and I'm having a hard time getting info on the grammar of Python - if anyone has a great resource I gladly welcome it. :)

```
def numberchoice():
    print "How much do you take?"
    choice = raw_input("> ")
    if "0" in choice or "1" in choice or "2" in choice: #OPTION ONE
    #if "0" or "1" or "2" in choice: #OPTION TWO
        how_much = int(choice)
    else:
        print "please type a number."
        numberchoice()
    if how_much < 50:
        exit("Nice, you're not greedy, you win!")
    if how_much > 50:
        exit("You greedy bastard!")
numberchoice()
```

The thing I don't understand is why OPTION ONE and TWO aren't interchangeable; if I use option one, and the user inputs an erroneous response - ie. letters instead of numbers - option one runs the "else" response, but option two just gives an error.  Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
if "0" or "1" or "2" in choice
```

This is an extremely common error for new programmers.

This could be read as

```
if '0' == true or '1' == true or '2' in choice
```

Do you see what the problem is now? `"0"`, being a non-empty string, will be true, and will always be true, so the rest of the checks are never even done.

Remember, `or` just checks for one of its operands to be true (or truthy). It doesn't have some intelligent behavior that allows it to read as English and operate as you'd expect.

Version 1 is correct, although further down the road you'll learn better ways of writing that.

Comment: It seems so simple and sensible when I read your answer. Thank you!